# Deleting questions

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I just voted for deleting a question for the first time.

If I understand that correctly then 15 votes are required to delete a question – and 18 users of this site (probably not all of them active) are capable of voting for deletion.

Is that correct? Has ever a question been deleted by voting? ;-)

**misunderstanding solved**

The message mentioning "13 votes" referred to the votes I had left on that day, not to the votes required yet to delete the question.

Comment: Voting to delete questions require > 20k rep, is it?

Answer (score 4):

Deleting questions only requires [10k](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), not [20k](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) (that's for deleting answers), so there's actually 54 users that can do it. It also only requires 3 votes by default; it [scales up based on question popularity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), but is capped at 10. I'm not sure where you got 15 from, but if you mouseover the "delete" link on a post it will say how many more votes are needed:

[image]

Comment: I guess it said "delete (1)" before I voted, and afterwards it said something like "13 more votes required". I didn't try mouseover, though. It seems strange to me that deleting questions is "easier" than deleting answers as deleting the question deletes the answers, too.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Questions have to be closed before the vote to delete can start. So (without ♦mod intervention) it takes a minimum of 5 people, 3 of which have to act twice, to delete a question, vs 3 people to delete an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can delete a question with undeleted answers.  We could try and see ;)  Also, they have to have been closed for at least 48 hours: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: @goldilocks You can delete questions with undeleted answers. 20k users are also not subject to the 48 hour limit, they can delete questions as soon as they're closed

Comment: @MichaelMrozek WRT 20k users and the 48 hour limit, I don't think so.  I don't have the option to delete stuff closed today here, and there are no more privileges left for me to earn.

Comment: @goldilocks Oh, they need to have a [score of -3 or lower](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user); I forgot that part